# How can I iterate over properties from a file?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

All my projects and their versions are defined in a properties file like this:

```
ProjectNameA=0.0.1
ProjectNameB=1.4.2
```

I'd like to iterate over all the projects, and use their names and versions in an Ant script.

At present I read the entire file using the property task, then iterate over a given list in a for loop like this:

```
<for list="ProjectNameA,ProjectNameB" param="project">
   <sequential>
    <echo message="@{project} has version ${@{project}}" />
   </sequential>
</for>
```

How can I avoid the hard-coding of the project names in the for loop?
Basically iterate over each line and extract the name and the version of a project as I go.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seeing as you're already using antcontrib `for`, how about making use of the [`propertyselector`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyselector.html) task:

```
<property file="properties.txt" prefix="projects."/>
<propertyselector property="projects" match="projects\.(.*)" select="\1"/>

<property file="properties.txt" />
<for list="${projects}" param="project">
    ...
</for>
```

The idea here is to read the properties once with the `projects` prefix, and use the resulting set of properties to build a comma-separated list of projects with the `propertyselector` task.  Then the properties are re-read *without* the prefix, so that your for loop can proceed as before.

Comment: Added relation to a given bug, and the sequential alement to the for element to make it more obvious.

Comment: Wanted to add an edit, but it was rejected. So I add it as a comment: the for task is not listed somehow in the antcontrib.properties in the latest jar. A workaround is to include it as an class with a name in a taskdef like it is stated in the bug report at http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2838574&group_id=36177&atid=416920

Comment: Thanks for the post Martin. For others who did not have things setup for ant contrib, you may need the following line too:
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>

Reference: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/index.html#intro

Answer (score 0):

Something you want to keep in mind, if you are reading additional .property files (besides build.properties) is scoping.   If you read an additional file (via the property file="foo.property") tag, ant will show that the file was read, and the properties loaded.  However, when you goto reference them, they come up un-defined.