# How Can I Get FDT & Ant To Loop Through Builds?

Tags: eclipse, ant, fdt

I want to have FDT loop through a list (or directory) of .AS files and output corresponding .SWFs.

I want to do this via Ant, instead of using FDT's launcher chain, and found the 'fdt.launch.application' Ant task [in the documentation here](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FDT_Ant_Tasks#fdt.launch.application). Can I use it to help me?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, you can simulate loops with Ant by using the ['for' or 'foreach'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056395/how-can-i-iterate-over-properties-from-a-file) Ant tasks. But you'll need to first install the tasks, which do not ship with Ant by default. [See here for more info on getting those tasks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608935/troubleshooting-failed-to-create-task-or-type-foreach-when-using-foreach)

You can then define the files and outputs to compile in a separate properties file - which perhaps you can also generate via Ant or just edit by hand. In the above link, the answer shows how to work with an external properties file.

When you do that you'll need to include the fdt `<fdt.launch.application>` compile task in your loop and use the variables you extract from the properties file.