# Iterating through a properties file

Tags: ant

I have a property file containing keys and values as shown below:

```
TC_name1=true
Tc_name2=false
```

I need an Ant script to iterate through this property file and get only the keys with value  equal to true.

Also I want to know whether it is possible to use an .ini file as our property file.

Please help me out with this as I googled, but was not able to find the solution.

Comment: you can find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056395/how-can-i-iterate-over-properties-from-a-file

Answer (score 4):

build.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="load">
    <target name="load">

        <!-- load the properties as plain text into a property -->
        <loadfile property="trueProps" srcfile="load.properties">
            <!-- only load affirmative values of properties -->
            <filterchain>
                <linecontainsregexp>
                    <regexp pattern="=\s*(true|yes|on)\s*$" />
                </linecontainsregexp>
            </filterchain>
            <!-- prefix for easy retrieval -->
            <filterchain>
                <prefixlines prefix="testing." />
            </filterchain>
        </loadfile>

        <!-- print the property contents -->
        <echo taskname="trueProps">${trueProps}</echo>

        <!-- extract the keys -->
        <loadresource property="trueKeys" >
            <string>${trueProps}</string>
            <filterchain>
                <replaceregex pattern="=\s*(true|yes|on)\s*$" replace="" />
            </filterchain>
        </loadresource>

        <!-- print the keys -->
        <echo taskname="trueKeys">${trueKeys}</echo>

        <!-- load the contents of the variable as ant properties -->
        <loadproperties>
            <string>${trueProps}</string>
        </loadproperties>

        <!-- confirm the properties are loaded as expected -->
        <echoproperties prefix="testing." />
    </target>
</project>
```

load.properties:

```
prop1=false
some_other=true
also_true=yes
yet_another=on
not_this=no

TC_name1=true
Tc_name2=false

some_other_match =yes
not_a_yes= false
```

output:

```
Buildfile: build.xml

load:
[trueProps] testing.some_other=true
[trueProps] testing.also_true=yes
[trueProps] testing.yet_another=on
[trueProps] testing.TC_name1=true
[trueProps] testing.some_other_match =yes
 [trueKeys] testing.some_other
 [trueKeys] testing.also_true
 [trueKeys] testing.yet_another
 [trueKeys] testing.TC_name1
 [trueKeys] testing.some_other_match 
[echoproperties] #Ant properties
[echoproperties] #Wed May 29 10:57:26 EDT 2013
[echoproperties] testing.TC_name1=true
[echoproperties] testing.also_true=yes
[echoproperties] testing.some_other=true
[echoproperties] testing.some_other_match=yes
[echoproperties] testing.yet_another=on

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that works without external plugins. Personally I'd embed a groovy script, but that would require an external jar.